Asymptotic of number of edges in a graph without k-cliques
I need to find asymptotic of number of edges in a graph on $n$ vertices without $k$ cliques (without $K_k$ subgraphs). I need to to it using Turan's theorem.
Here is my attempt: let $\alpha(G) = k - 1$, so if we look at the graph complement we get $\omega(\overline{G})=\alpha(G)=k-1$ so there is no k-cliques in $\overline{G}$. Now let's write $|E(\overline{G})| = C_n^2-|E(G)|\le C_n^2-\frac{n^2}{2(k-1)}+\frac{n}{2} = \frac{n^2(k-2)}{2(k-1)}$
I'd like to get some equivalency but $\frac{n^2(k-2)}{2(k-1)} \sim \frac{n^2}{2}$ is wrong. so how could we answer the question?

Where did $n^2/2$ come from in the first place?

@MishaLavrov, it's just an example of some equivalency asymptotic that would contain $n$ (and this example is wrong), I just wanted clarify what I wanna do

What don't you like about $\frac{n^2(k-2)}{2(k-1)}$, then?
